# Non-linear dimensionality reduction for detecting coordinate systems

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pca, dimensionality-reduction, nonlinear

I am trying to find a way to automatically find the appropriate coordinate system for a physical problem.

For example, in the case of a simple pendulum, polar coordinates are the most appropriate ones. I have the data for the x,y cartesian coordinates of the pendulum at various times. I would like to be able to jump from this to the angular data at a given time.

I feel that this is a form of dimensionality reduction. Could we use auto-encoders for this or are methods such as ISOMAP or CDA more appropriate?

I feel that PCA would not work well for this problem as I need to perform a non-linear dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Is this task a learning exercise or are you really pondering about using autoencoders to obtain phase information from pendulum simulations?

Comment: Because there's an analytical solution to that, no need for fancy machine learning.

Comment: How is this dimensionality reduction? You start with two parameters (angle and length) and you end up with two (x and y)>

What is it that you want to automate?

Comment: Yes but the problem has one degree of freedom. Ok dimensionality reduction may not be the correct word. But I feel that autoencoders could work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, in the case of a simple pendulum, polar coordinates are
>   the most appropriate ones. I have the data for the x,y cartesian
>   coordinates of the pendulum at various times. I would like to be able
>   to jump from this to the angular data at a given time.
>   I feel that this is a form of dimensionality reduction. Could we use
>   auto-encoders for this or are methods such as ISOMAP or CDA more
>   appropriate?

And you're correct. An autoencoder could work here, since it's a nonlinear problem, but would not simply tell you that the latent dimensionality of the two-dimensional position distribution is $\theta=\operatorname{tg}((x-\bar x)/(y-\bar y))$. It would only allow you to estimate the intrinsic dimensionality of your problem, one, since the radius is invariant.

> I feel that PCA would not work well for this problem as I need to
>   perform a non-linear dimensionality reduction.

Your intuition is right, since PCA is a linear dimensionality reduction method.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. So it isn't possible to get the value of the angular positions just from the x,y cartesian coordinates? Perhaps by varying the architecture of the autoencoder neural network.

Comment: @TriposG it's not uniquely defined. A 1-D space where $t=\theta$ is just as good  at explaining your data as a 1-D space where $t = 1000 \theta$

Comment: right but atleast the ratios would be the same?

Comment: @TriposG no, the autoencoder could learn a nonlinear transformation of the phase as well, such as $t=\theta^3$, which has equal explanatory power to all the other approximations

Comment: ok. Do you have any suggestion on how to go from x,y coordinates to theta using autoencoders? Or is this a very difficult task?

Comment: or will it learn the Taylor series expansion

Comment: Hi, @TriposG , CV is a QA site, and so it does not lend itself well for lengthy discussions. You could read a bit more about autoencoders and then feel free to add more questions to the site and link me here if you want.